# DBMS_RESOURCE_MANAGER limit IOPS or MBPS

Tags: oracle, dbms-resource-manager

Does DBMS_RESOURCE_MANAGER have limit io bandwidth?

I want reporting group to be limited to some mbps. During peak hours our database disks are 100% loaded, because reporting groups are selecting many rows.

I want  somehow to limit io resource without canceling their selects.

Comment: I believe that you cannot do that with Resource Manager. In Resource Manager you can just perform some action after some megabytes or IOs. But if Oracle DB runs on RHEL/OEL 6 or newer you can write Linux script which finds such sessions theirs PIDs and then those assigns those processes to certain CGroup. And CGroup can be limited  to some IOPS or mbps.

Answer (score 1):

By making those processes slower you als stretch the period with pain for both the regular users as well as the etl processes. We normally solve this by assigning a dedicated replica to the etl/reporting processes. That replicate can be tuned to better support the etl processing and it removes the need to put the extra pressure on the production database.

Resource manager can be used to prevent long running queries from starting at all. Problem here is that the estimates it uses are not always correct which might cause regular queries to be rejected. So be careful.

Answer (score -2):

From the [Oracle® Database Administrator's Guide 11g Release 2 (11.2)](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e17120/dbrm001.htm#CHDIGAHB)

> **Automatic Consumer Group Switching**
>
> This method enables you to control resource allocation by specifying criteria that, if met, causes the automatic switching of a session to a specified consumer group. Typically, this method is used to switch a session from a high-priority consumer group—one that receives a high proportion of system resources—to a lower priority consumer group because that session exceeded the expected resource consumption for a typical session in the group.
>
> See ["Specifying Automatic Switching by Setting Resource Limits"](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e17120/dbrm004.htm#CHDDCGGG) for more information.

Also from the [Oracle® Database Administrator's Guide 11g Release 2 (11.2)](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e17120/dbrm004.htm#CHDDCGGG):

> **Specifying Automatic Switching by Setting Resource Limits**
>
> When you create a resource plan directive for a consumer group, you can specify limits for CPU and I/O resource consumption for sessions in that group. You can then specify the action that is to be taken if any single call within a session exceeds one of these limits. The possible actions are the following:
>
> - The session is dynamically switched to a designated consumer group.
> - The target consumer group is typically one that has lower resource allocations. The session's user must have switch privileges on the new consumer group, otherwise the switch cannot occur. See ["Granting and Revoking the Switch Privilege"](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e17120/dbrm004.htm#i1008409) for more information.
>   *The session is killed (terminated).
> - The session's current SQL statement is aborted.
>
> The following are the resource plan directive attributes that are involved in this type of automatic session switching.
>
> - SWITCH_GROUP
> - SWITCH_TIME
> - SWITCH_ESTIMATE
> - SWITCH_IO_MEGABYTES
> - SWITCH_IO_REQS
> - SWITCH_FOR_CALL
>
> See ["Creating Resource Plan Directives"](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e17120/dbrm003.htm#i1008232) for descriptions of these attributes.
>
> Switches occur for sessions that are running and consuming resources, not waiting for user input or waiting for CPU cycles. After a session is switched, it continues in the target consumer group until it becomes idle, at which point it is switched back to its original consumer group. However, if SWITCH_FOR_CALL is set to TRUE, the Resource Manager does not wait until the session is idle to return it to its original resource consumer group. Instead, the session is returned when the current top-level call completes. A **top-level call** in PL/SQL is an entire PL/SQL block treated as one call. A top-level call in SQL is an individual SQL statement.